# convex sets , and some union of lines between two sets

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let´s denote $$
[x,y] = \left\{ {u \in \mathbb{R}^n :u = tx + \left( {1 - t} \right)y\,,\,\,\,0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1} \right\}
$$

Let $X , Y$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n $; let´s denote $$
X*Y = \bigcup\limits_{x\,\, \in X\,,\,\,y\, \in \,Y} {[x,y]} 
$$

Prove that if $X , Y$ are convex sets then also is $ X*Y $ .
Obviously the only non-trivial case is where we take $u_0,u_1$ with $$
u_i  = \alpha _i x_i  + \beta _i y_i\,, \quad i = 1,2\,,\quad \alpha _1  + \beta _1  = \,\alpha _2  + \beta _2  = 1\,,\quad x_i  \in X\,,\,y_i  \in Y
$$ and we want to see if for any $
{0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1}
$ ,  $
tu_1  + \left( {1 - t} \right)u_2 \, \in X*Y
$, i.e.
$$
\exists \,x^*  \in X\,,\,y^*  \in Y\,,\,0 \leqslant t^*  \leqslant 1:\,\,t^* x^*  + \left( {1 - t^* } \right)y^*  = tu_1  + \left( {1 - t} \right)u_2 
$$
Note at least that $$
tu_1  + \left( {1 - t} \right)u_2  = t\left( {\alpha _1 x_1  + \beta _1 y_1 } \right) + \left( {1 - t} \right)\left( {\alpha _2 x_2  + \beta _2 y_2 } \right)
\;:$$ it´s a convex combination of $ x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ , thus $X*Y$ at least is contained in the convex hull of $
X \cup Y
$
But I don´t know how to prove that $X*Y$ is convex

PD: sorry for the blablabla

Comment: Have you tried showing that the convex hull of $X\cup Y$ is a subset of $X*Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Set $A=t\alpha_1+(1-t)\alpha_2$ and $B=t\beta_1+(1-t)\beta_2$. Then $A+B=t+(1-t)=1$ and
$$\begin{align}& t\left( {\alpha _1 x_1  + \beta _1 y_1 } \right) + \left( {1 - t} \right)\left( {\alpha _2 x_2  + \beta _2 y_2 } \right) 
\\=& t\alpha_1x_1+(1-t)\alpha_2 x_2 + t\beta_1y_1+(1-t)\beta_2 y_2
\\=& A\left(\frac{t\alpha_1}{A} x_1+\frac{(1-t)\alpha_2}A x_2\right) + B\left(\frac{t\beta_1}{B}y_1 + \frac{(1-t)\beta_2}B y_2\right)
\end{align}
$$